# Is there any good way to get new Array from new Array when things in Array has common factors?(react.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Suppose there is an Array that has some objects like below

```
[{name:"Bruce wayne" age:42 DOA:true},{name: "Dick grayson" age:28 DOA:true},{name:"Jason todd" age:24 DOA:false}]
```

and I want to get a new Array with Objects which DOA is true (bruce and dick).

Is there any good API or something to do this?

your help is going to be appreciated Thx!

Comment: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const data = [{
  name: "Bruce wayne",
  age: 42,
  DOA: true
}, {
  name: "Dick grayson",
  age: 28,
  DOA: true
}, {
  name: "Jason todd",
  age: 24,
  DOA: false
}];

console.log(data.filter(obj => obj.DOA));
```

*Mind that your JSON was also invalid.*

Comment: This is an ***often*** repeated duplicate question. We close those in favor of the previous versions so that we don't have a million different answers to the same question.

Comment: oh then, what if I want to get objects which DOA is false?

Comment: @user15508209  `obj.DOA === false`

Comment: @user15508209 - Or `obj => !obj.DOA` assuming you won't have other falsy values like `0` or `""`.